# I would like to create a new folder in google drive named by cells in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am new to google AppScript as a service. I have a spreadsheet that is as-of-yet unfilled. Over time, the spreadsheet will be filled with items. I would like to create a cell function that creates a new folder in my google drive according to the item title identified as a neighbouring cell in the spreadsheet. E.g. A1 = 'Orange', B1 = [=NEWFOLDER(A1)]. The idea being that the function is placed in all cells in the 'B' column, and when a value in the 'A' column is changed/added, a new folder is created with the name specified in the row-adjacent cell. A2 = 'Pear', B2 = NEWFOLDER(A2).
I'm aware you cannot create custom functions that use DriveApp, but is there a workaround?
Seen a few discussions online but I haven't found anything where the cell address is variable. I have really tried to find a good solution!

I currently have a single button assigned to a function that creates a folder according to the selected cell value using getActiverange().getValue(). This is fine but ideally I would have a function that sits in every cell in a column and monitors the adjacent cell for edit/change then creates a folder with that name; no need for an active cell. Is it possible?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: A custom function is a dynamic formula that constantly recalculates. This is one of the reasons (besides that fact that Custom functions can't access Drive) that this is inappropriate for this the purpose described. BUT... say you had checkboxes in cell B1, B2, etc, and an `onEdit` function that watches Column B. You check the checkbox when you want to create a folder, the script tests if that folder already exists, creates the folder and deletes the value in cell A1, A2, etc and unchecks the checkbox in Column B so that you don't accidentally create the same folder ad infinitum.